# remove key from dictionary function

Tags: python, dictionary, del

I am trying to create a void function that removes strings from a dictionary.

I need to make sure that the key is in the dictionary and then that the value is in that specific key.

This is what I have thus far, but there appears to be some sort of dilemma. Any advice?

```
def f(d, n1, n2):
    if n1 in d1 and d1[n1] == n2:
        del n2
        if d1[n1] == []:
            del n1
```

Comment: Pro tip: show us what happens, and what you expected to happen instead. In this case, there are no error messages, which is something worth stating.

Comment: Python doesn't have `void` functions.  *All* functions in python return something... if you don't explicitly return something, python adds a `return None` to the end of the function for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are removing the `n2` and `n1` local names, and are not touching the dictionary.

To delete from a dictionary, you need to apply `del` to the key:

```
def f(d, n1, n2):
    if n1 in d1 and d1[n1] == n2:
        del d1[n1]
```

You may want to use some more descriptive names:

```
def remove_item(dct, key, value):
    if key in dct and dct[key] == value:
        del dct[key]
```

and, because testing your code is always a good idea, a demo:

```
>>> demo = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'ham'}
>>> def remove_item(dct, key, value):
...     if key in dct and dct[key] == value:
...         del dct[key]
... 
>>> remove_item(demo, 'monty', 'python')
>>> demo
{'spam': 'ham', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> remove_item(demo, 'spam', 'eggs')
>>> demo
{'spam': 'ham', 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> remove_item(demo, 'spam', 'ham')
>>> demo
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

If your values are lists and you need to remove just one of the values, then you need to use `list.remove()`, or use a list comprehension.

First the `list.remove()` option, which removes just *one* value. If the value is repeated, only the first occurrence is removed:

```
def remove_item(dct, key, value):
    if key in dct:
        if dct[key] == value:
            del dct[key]
        elif isinstance(dct[key], list) and value in dct[key]:
            dct[key].remove(value)
```

The list comprehension will remove *all* copies of the value:

```
def remove_item(dct, key, value):
    if key in dct:
        if dct[key] == value:
            del dct[key]
        elif isinstance(dct[key], list):
            dct[key] = [v for v in dct[key] if v != value]
```

Demo of `list.remove()`:

```
>>> demo = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz', 'bar']}
>>> def remove_item(dct, key, value):
...     if key in dct:
...         if dct[key] == value:
...             del dct[key]
...         elif isinstance(dct[key], list) and value in dct[key]:
...             dct[key].remove(value)
... 
>>> remove_item(demo, 'foo', 'bar')
>>> demo
{'foo': ['baz', 'bar']}
```

Demo of the list comprehension:

```
>>> demo = {'foo': ['bar', 'baz', 'bar']}
>>> def remove_item(dct, key, value):
...     if key in dct:
...         if dct[key] == value:
...             del dct[key]
...         elif isinstance(dct[key], list):
...             dct[key] = [v for v in dct[key] if v != value]
... 
>>> remove_item(demo, 'foo', 'bar')
>>> demo
{'foo': ['baz']}
```

Comment: I can do that just fine, but i'm having problems when there are more than 1 values that are associated with a key. For example, demo = {'x': [1,2,3]}.

Comment: @BobDarren: Then you need to *specify* such constraints in your question. You haven't given us any sample input, for example.

Comment: It is easy enough to try out, isn't it? Yes, if `value` is a list, and `dct[key]` is itself a list *containing* another list that is equal to `value`, then the method works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the dict.pop(key) instead of del.

You could do something like this:

```
def f(d, n1, n2):
    if d.has_key(n1) and d[n1] == n2:
        d.pop(n1)
    return d
```

Comment: This does more work than `del d[n1]` does; it returns the popped value, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}                                                            


def fun(_d, _k, _v):                                                            
    return {key: _d[key] for key in _d                                          
            if not (_k == key and _v == _d[key])}                                


print fun(d, 'b', 1)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```